# Fluid design in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I'm trying to create a somewhat "responsive" design with ttk (tkinter). The basic placement of widgets is no problem at all, but making it fluid with the width of the program is something I cannot achieve. In CSS I know it's possible to say something along the lines of '"float: left" for all containers' and the page would adapt to the screen size. I haven't found something similar to that in Tkinter and frames.

My basic test program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
from ttkthemes import ThemedTk, THEMES

class quick_ui(ThemedTk):
    def __init__(self):
        ThemedTk.__init__(self, themebg=True)
        self.geometry('{}x{}'.format(900, 150))
        self.buttons = {}

        self.frame1 = ttk.Frame(self)
        self.frame1.pack(side="left")
        self.frame2 = ttk.Frame(self)
        self.frame2.pack(side="left")

        #------------------------------------------------------- BUTTONS
        i = 0
        while (i < 5):
            i += 1
            self.buttons[i]= ttk.Button(self.frame1,
                                            text='List 1 All ' + str(i),
                                            command=self.dump)
            self.buttons[i].pack(side="left")


        while (i < 10):
            i += 1
            self.buttons[i]= ttk.Button(self.frame2,
                                            text='List 2 All ' + str(i),
                                            command=self.dump)
            self.buttons[i].pack(side="left")

    def dump(self):
        print("dump called")

quick = quick_ui()
quick.mainloop()
```

This creates a window with 10 buttons all besides each other. 
When I shrink the window to the point that the buttons no longer fit on the screen, I would like the buttons to appear below each other

So what I did was add a resize listener and setup the following method:

```
    def resize(self, event):
        w=self.winfo_width()
        h=self.winfo_height()
        # print("width: " + str(w) + ", height: " + str(h))

        if(w < 830):
            self.frame1.config(side="top")
            self.frame2.config(side="top")
```

But `Frame` doesn't has the property `side`, which is a parameter given to the method `pack`. So that didn't work either.

And now I'm lost. I've spend way to long on this, trying grids and other solutions, but I've got the feeling that I'm missing out on one simple, but very important setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I've created a (hackish) solution, which is fine due to it being a very internal program. Since no answer is given in the mean time, I'll provide my solution here. It probably has a lot of room for improvements, but I hope that this can give somebody in the future some pointers on how to tackle this problem by him(or her) self.*

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import re
import sys
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk
from ttkthemes import ThemedTk, THEMES

import subprocess
import os
from tkinter.constants import UNITS
import json
from functools import partial


class quick_ui(ThemedTk):

    def __init__(self):
        ThemedTk.__init__(self, themebg=True)
        self.minsize(600, 250)
        self.elems = {}
        self.resize_after_id = None


        #------------------------------------------------------- Window menu bar contents
        self.menubar = tkinter.Menu(self)
        self.menubar.add_command(label="Open", command = self.dump)
        self.menubar.add_command(label="Refresh", command = self.dump)
        self.config(menu=self.menubar)

        # Theme menu
        self.themeMenu = tkinter.Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=0)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="Theme", menu=self.themeMenu)
        self.themeMenu.add_command(label="DEFAULT", command=partial(self.dump, "default"))


        #---------------------------------------------------------------------- top_frame
        self.top_frame = ttk.Frame(self)
        self.top_frame.pack( side = tkinter.TOP, expand='YES', fill='both', padx=10)

        self.top_top_frame = ttk.Frame(self.top_frame)
        self.top_top_frame.pack(side=tkinter.TOP, expand='YES', fill='both')

        self.top_bottom_frame = ttk.Frame(self.top_frame)
        self.top_bottom_frame.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM)

        self.top_bottom_top_frame = ttk.Frame(self.top_frame)
        self.top_bottom_top_frame.pack(side=tkinter.TOP)


        self.top_bottom_bottom_frame = ttk.Frame(self.top_frame)
        self.top_bottom_bottom_frame.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM)

        #------------------------------------------------------------------- bottom_frame
        self.bottom_frame = ttk.Frame(self, relief="sunken")
        self.bottom_frame.pack( side = tkinter.BOTTOM, 
                                expand='YES', 
                                fill='both', 
                                padx=10, 
                                pady=10 )

        #------------------------------------------------------- BUTTONS
        i = 0
        while (i < 15):
            self.elems[i]=ttk.Button(self.top_bottom_top_frame,
                                                text='List All ' + str(i),
                                                command=self.dump)
            i += 1


        self.label_test_strings1 = ttk.Label(self.top_top_frame, text='Test strings1')
        self.label_test_strings2 = ttk.Label(self.top_bottom_frame, text='Test strings2')
        self.label_test_strings4 = ttk.Label(self.top_bottom_bottom_frame, text='Test strings4')

        self.label_test_strings1.pack(side = tkinter.TOP)
        self.label_test_strings2.pack(side = tkinter.TOP)
        self.label_test_strings4.pack(side = tkinter.TOP)


        self.placeElems()
        # Setup a hook triggered when the configuration (size of window) changes
        self.bind('<Configure>', self.resize)


    def placeElems(self):
        for index in self.elems:
            self.elems[index].grid(row=0, column=index, padx=5, pady=5)


    # ------------------------------------------------------ Resize event handler
    def resize(self, event):
        # Set a low "time-out" for resizing, to limit the change of "fighting" for growing and shrinking
        if self.resize_after_id is not None:
            self.after_cancel(self.resize_after_id)
        self.resize_after_id = self.after(200, self.resize_callback)


    # ------------------------------------------------------ Callback for the resize event handler
    def resize_callback(self):
        # The max right position of the program
        windowMaxRight = self.winfo_rootx() + self.winfo_width()

        # Some basic declarations
        found = False
        willAdd = False
        maxColumn = 0
        currIndex = 0
        currColumn = 0
        currRow = 0
        counter = 0
        last_rootx = 0
        last_maxRight = 0

        # Program is still starting up, so ignore this one
        if(windowMaxRight < 10):
            return

        # Loop through all the middle bar elements
        for child in self.top_bottom_frame.children.values():
            # Calculate the max right position of this element
            elemMaxRight = child.winfo_rootx() + child.winfo_width() + 10

            # If we already found the first 'changable' child, we need to remove the following child's also
            if(found == True):
                # Is the window growing?
                if(willAdd == True):
                    # Check to see if we have room for one more object
                    calcMaxRight = last_maxRight + child.winfo_width() + 20
                    if(calcMaxRight < windowMaxRight):
                        maxColumn = counter + 1
                # Remove this child from the view, to add it again later
                child.grid_forget()

            # If this child doesn't fit on the screen anymore
            elif(elemMaxRight >= windowMaxRight):
                # Remove this child from the view, to add it again later
                child.grid_forget()
                currIndex = counter
                maxColumn = counter
                currRow = 1
                found = True

            else:
                # If this child's x position is lower than the last child
                # we can asume it's on the next row
                if(child.winfo_rootx() < last_rootx):
                    # Check to see if we have room for one more object on the first row
                    calcMaxRight = last_maxRight + child.winfo_width() + 20
                    if(calcMaxRight < windowMaxRight):
                        child.grid_forget()
                        currIndex = counter
                        currColumn = counter
                        maxColumn = counter + 1
                        found = True
                        willAdd = True

            # Save some calculation data for the next run
            last_rootx = child.winfo_rootx()
            last_maxRight = elemMaxRight
            counter += 1

        # If we removed some elements from the UI
        if(found == True):
            counter = 0
            # Loop through all the middle bar elements (including removed ones)
            for child in self.top_bottom_frame.children.values():
                # Ignore the elements still in place
                if(counter < currIndex):
                    counter += 1
                    continue

                # If we hit our maxColumn count, move to the next row
                if(currColumn == maxColumn):
                    currColumn = 0
                    currRow += 1

                # Place this element on the UI again
                child.grid(row=currRow, column=currColumn, padx=5, pady=5)
                currColumn += 1
                counter += 1


    def dump(self):
        print("dump called")


quick = quick_ui()
quick.mainloop()
```